# Sorting by two columns conditionally

Tags: mysql, sorting

Column a has category ids, column b has set orders:

```
+-------------+-----------+
| category_id | set_order |
+-------------+-----------+
|          80 | null      |
|          81 | null      |
|          82 | null      |
|          83 | 2         |
|          84 | null      |
|          85 | 4         |
|          86 | null      |
|          87 | null      |
|          88 | null      |
|          89 | null.     |
|          90 | null      |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Desired output is:

```
+----+
| 90 |
| 83 |
| 89 |
| 85 |
| 88 |
| 87 |
| 86 |
| 84 |
| 82 |
| 81 |
| 80 |
+----+
```

Please help how to write the order by clause. 83 has value 2 in column b, hence is to appear 2nd in ordering. 85 has value 4 in column b, hence is to appear 4th in ordering.

Comment: Both columns have equal number of value.Some values in column a have values in Column b. Rest of values in column a have corresponding nulls in column b. I have to sort column A in descending in general. But those values in column a which have values in column b have in appear in fixed position.Example, 83 has value 2. So it has to appear 2nd.85 has 4th, so it has to appear 4th.

Comment: Paul , are you there? am i clear in my explanation now ?

Comment: So for rows with a not null column set_orders the set_orders value gives the position in the output. The column where  set_orders is null are sorted category_id in the output. Why do you need such a strange sort order?

Comment: miracle173:Yes, you have put it correctly.This is for display of "databoxes" with corresponding category ids,on front end for a web site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job better done on application layer. Databases are not suited for this. Just do

```
SELECT category_id, set_order FROM your_table ORDER BY category_id DESC;
```

Then write a function that rearranges the array returned by above query.

**For fun** I did it in MySQL, just to let you see, how complicated this can be. So you see it's doable, note though, that this can be horrible performance-wise.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`category_id` int, `set_order` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`category_id`, `set_order`)
VALUES
    (80, NULL),
    (81, NULL),
    (82, NULL),
    (83, '2'),
    (84, NULL),
    (85, '4'),
    (86, NULL),
    (87, NULL),
    (88, NULL),
    (89, NULL),
    (90, NULL)
;
```

Query:

```
SELECT category_id FROM (
    SELECT
    category_id, set_order
    , IF(set_order IS NULL, @newOrder := IF(@newOrder + 1 IN (SELECT set_order FROM t WHERE set_order IS NOT NULL), @newOrder + 2, @newOrder + 1), NULL) new_order
    FROM t,
    (SELECT @newOrder := 0) var_init_subquery_alias
    ORDER BY category_id DESC
) sq ORDER BY COALESCE(new_order, set_order);
```

Result:

```
+-------------+
| category_id |
+-------------+
|          90 |
|          83 |
|          89 |
|          85 |
|          88 |
|          87 |
|          86 |
|          84 |
|          82 |
|          81 |
|          80 |
+-------------+
```

Comment: Looks like fun to me. +1 !!!

Comment: @Bhargava When it solves your problem you should accept the answer by clicking the check to the left of the answer. This way others also know, that the issue is solved.